# Convert Cell Content to Hyperlink in MySQL Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a MySQL table in datagridview windows form (built in visual basic). Once column in my table has email addresses in every row. I would like the users to be able to click on the cell and it will automatically open an email message from Outlook with the email address in the cell populated in the 'to:' section of email.

I've been unsuccessful adding it into the query and in the class Databindingcomplete.

```
select name, email, phone, address from t1 where name is like 'A%'
```

Comment: Are you saying you haven't been able to show the data in the datagridview?  Also, can we see your select statement?

Comment: I am able to show the data, but I want the email address that is displayed in the cells of a particular column to be a clickable hyperlink. I apologize for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datagridview cell click event.

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.CellClick
  If MyDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText = "email" then        
    Dim selectedEMailCell As DataGridViewCell = MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
    If selectedEMailCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then       
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & selectedEMailCell.Value.ToString)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```